# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null Stack trace:Database->query('SELECT jobs .*,...')Job->getAllJobs()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get the output if i remove `// $template->jobs = $job->getAllJobs(); //` but it is not what i expected as it  does not take the data from the database.. I`have tried most of the answers from this page related to this problem but still get this kind of error..

```
<?php

class Database{

    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;



    public function __construct(){
        //set DSN

        $dsn= 'mysqli:host=' .$this->host .';dbname='. $this->dbname;
        $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION 
        );

        //PDO Instances
        try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);       
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }  

    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }
    //bind values after obtaining the values
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if(is_null($type)){
            switch(true){
                case is_int ( $value ) :
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
                case is_bool ( $value ) :
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
                case is_null( $value ) :
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
                default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();          
    }

    public function resultSet(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
  }
//Code for job class

<?php
  class Job{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->db = new Database();
    }
    //get all jobs
    public function getAllJobs(){

      $this->db->query("SELECT jobs .*, categories.name AS cname FROM jobs NATURAL JOIN categories ON jobs.category_id = categories.id ORDER BY post_date DESC "); //jobs.category_id==foreignkey
      $results = $this->db->resultSet();
      return $results;
   }
}

///code that caused problem
$job = new Job;
$template->jobs = $job->getAllJobs();
```

The error occured as:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\lib\database.php:32 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\lib\job.php(11): Database->query('SELECT jobs .*,...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\homejoblister.php(7): Job->getAllJobs() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\lib\database.php on line 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `$dsn` variable, you are setting the DSN prefix to `mysqli`. There is no database-type `mysqli` (there is an API, but that still connects to the MySQL database).

Simply set the database-type to `mysql` instead!

```php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' .$this->host .';dbname='. $this->dbname.';charset=utf8mb4';
```

I also set the charset here to utf8, which will come in handy if you're using non-ASCII characters.